# Wordpress download manager plugin showing attached file is missing/deleted?

Tags: plugins

I have installed wordpress download manager plugin in wordpress 4.4.3 version. When I uploaded file and plublish. It is showing file-not-found.txt. What is the issue. It is working fine in my local machine. A download -manager file folder is created in uploads.In my main site the folder is not created. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't modify anything.I just deactivated and activated the download manager plugin. It's working. After activation it is created the download manager file folder in uploads folder.